# Is it appropriate to perfrom IO::unsafeRunSync on the same instance multiple times?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I have a question about `IO` monad. I opened some `InputStream` and want to use `IO` to read from it. Here is the example:

```
def read(io: IO[Option[Array[Byte]]]): IO[Unit] = IO {
  io.unsafeRunSync() match {
    case Some(b) => 
         //do some with b
         read(io)
    case None => 
         ()
  }
}
```

The thing I'm confused about is that I read from the same `IO` instance multiple times modifying its state. It does not look like referential transparent method. Is it common to do this way or there is something more FP style?

Comment: You don't want to invoke `unsafeRunSync()` in your library code. You only invoke it _once_ on the very outer layer, e.g. in the `main` method.

Comment: `IO { io.unsafeRunSync() ... }` seems suspicious. Are you still defining the pure immutable plan represented by `IO`, or are you running it already?